# Word(s) to describe a set of things, which can't be empty

Tags: word-choice

I'm a programmer, and in my case students need to pick from a set of exams. They get to choose which ones but they must select at least 2 and at most 3.

I've been trying to find a way to refer to such exams. I've thought of:

- Elective Exams
- Opt-in Exams

Given English is not my mother tongue, I was wondering if there is a better way to name these type of exams.

PS: The title of the post is a bit strange, I just couldn't explain this in another way.

Comment: The latter, the exams are the ones being chosen from a list.

Comment: It's a term used in a really long document. Also, when building user interfaces I need to keep it compact. In headers it appears as "Requirements for [adj] exams", or another one "students will be better informed to choose the right exams from the [adj] exams".

Comment: I think you may be muddying things by juxtaposing the set of exams *from which some must be chosen*, and the *subset actually chosen*. On the other hand, I'm not convinced common parlance has standard terminology for that distinction. Or indeed, as Raku says, simple ways to distinguish whether a *chosen subset* can be an empty set or must contain some minimum number of elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know they're all called "electives" in English. Other languages, e.g. German, distinguish between

- mandatory elective (you have to choose n out of m, "Wahlpflichtfach")
- voluntary elective (you are free to choose none, some or all, "Wahlfach")

Comment: Interesting! "Mandatory elective exam" sounds pretty good. At first, it sounded a bit odd, but it grew on me. I think it makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 3):

A phrasing that may be of use to you in this context is *elective requirements*, conveying as it does that the choice of what exams to take is discretionary (elective), but there are minimum standards to be met (requirements).

Comment: Or, to flip it around, *required electives*.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I hesitate to use that formulation because it starts sounding a lot more oxymoronic that way.

Comment: Thank you. I like it; however, I would really like to keep the word "exam" in the construct.

Comment: @Ingenu: Easy enough; speak of "elective exam requirements".

Comment: @chaos I thought of that too, but it didn't sit with me well. In "elective requirements", "requirements" ~ "exams", while in "elective exam requirements", "requirements" refer to something else that is different from exam, because exam is already in the construct.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote in your comment: *It's a term used in a really long document. Also, when building user interfaces I need to keep it compact. In headers it appears as "Requirements for [adj] exams", or another one "students will be better informed to choose the right exams from the [adj] exams".*

How about referring to the exams as *chosen* if the students have already chosen, "Requirements for chosen exams"

And if they have not already chosen, you could say *offered* exams.

"Students will be better informed about choosing the right exams from those offered."

I would hope the instructions make it very clear that they have to choose 2 or 3 of the offered exams.